# c-lightning missing outputs

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, lost-transactions, funds, submarine-swaps

A few days ago I did a submarine swap in order to rebalance a channel of mine. I opted to be refunded on-chain using a brand-new address generated with c-lightning `newaddr` command. I used the `p2sh` address (aka starting with 3...) because last time I had some issues with the `bech32` version.
Here is the point: the on-chain transaction has (at time of writing) more than 80 confirmations, but my c-lightning node still cannot show the output with the `listfunds` command. 
Using `dev-rescan-outputs` didn't get any results as well. 
Am I miss something? Have that utxo gone lost?

Comment: your not bitcoin is update to the network?

Comment: absolutely yes, up and running

Comment: So `lightning-cli getinfo` has the same blockheight as `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo` and it matches what blockexplorers say is the latest block? You can try rescanning using `--rescan=-confirmationheight` (notice the minus in front of the absolute height).

Comment: both have 608865 as **block-height**

Comment: rescan completed, no results at all. Really concerned of losing those funds

Comment: No worries, if the funds are there, we should be able to recover them. Might just be a regression that we fail to look for `p2sh` outputs.

Comment: For more flexibility in debugging this issue we migrated the discussion here https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/issues/3359

Comment: We will write a summary here once the issue has been resolved with the necessary details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readers, this issue has been solved by @cdecker here: https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/issues/3359.

TL;DR: Use [the `--rescan` startup parameter of `lightningd`](https://lightning.readthedocs.io/lightningd-config.5.html#general-options).